# can't use jsplumb with second function

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I'm getting my instance like this:

```
jsp  = jsPlumb.getInstance();
jsp.setContainer(_domnodeId);
jsp.ready(function(){

//doing some stuff - connecting boxes with arrows...

    var conn2 = jsp.connect({
                source:     boxSST_IPMRS_COBRAIP.boxId,
                target:     boxCOBRA_IM.boxId
            });
    }
```

result:

[image]

in another function I'm doing the same:

```
jsp  = jsPlumb.getInstance();
jsp.setContainer(_domnodeId);

    jsp.ready(function(){   
        //var dynamicAnchor = [ [ 0.2,1,0.5 ],  [ 0.2, 1, 0.5 ], "Top", "Bottom" ];
        var common = {
                  anchor:[ "Continuous", { faces:["bottom","right"] }],
            endpoint:   "Blank",
            connector:[ "Bezier", { curviness:50 }, common ],
            overlays:   [
                            ["Arrow", {location:1, width:10, length:10}],
                        ]
            };

        jsp.connect({
            source: boxes.b1.boxId,
            target: boxes.b2.boxId
        }, common);
}
```

[image]

The arrows are all moving to the left,top corner...
var jsp is global and I cleared _domnodeId at the beginning of my second function. Any suggestions?

clearing my domnodeID:

```
function clean(container){
    //remove everything
    $("#" + container)
            .children()
            .not('nav')
            .remove();

    // box id counter
    window.EvmClasses.chartBox.boxId = 0;
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, what happens if you remove `faces:["bottom","right"]` from the anchor? I haven't tested this yet, and It's just a plain assumption from someone who never use jsplumb before.

Comment: Can you post a bit more code, or even better create a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/?html,output) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t) for this?

Answer (score 1):

> I cleared _domnodeId at the beginning of my second function

How did you done that? It seems to me that you didn't clear it properly.

Did you read ["Removing"](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/removing.html) section of the manual?

> If you have configured a DOM element with jsPlumb in any way you
>   should use jsPlumb to remove the element from the DOM (as opposed to
>   using something like jQuery's remove function, for example).

Please read it thoroughly. You may need either `jsPlumb.empty`, `deleteEveryEndpoint`, or `reset`.

Comment: I tried: jsPlumb.detachEveryConnection();
 jsPlumb.deleteEveryEndpoint();
 jsPlumb.reset();
 jsPlumb.empty();
 jsPlumb.empty();... all with no effect

Comment: In the code that you've added to the question you are removing via jQuery's `remove`, which is wrong. It's clearly stated that you shouldn't remove jsPlumb elements in that way. Have you tried those functions *instead* of jQuery's `remove`? Either that should help or removing individual elements via `jsPlumb.remove("element1");`, as said in the manual.

Comment: Did you run those functions on jsPlumb's instance, `jsp`? And `empty` requires an argument, in your case that would be like `jsp.empty(container);`